# MySQL2 gem won't install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2, gitlab

I have been trying to install Gitlab on my Ubuntu 12.04 server for a long time, and all goes well until I run `bundle install`.

It says it is unable to install MySQL2 but gives no reason or corrective action.

```
home/gitlab/gitlab$ sudo -u gitlab -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (10.0.1) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.3.7) 
Using activesupport (3.2.9) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.9) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.2.1) 
Using actionpack (3.2.9) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.12) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.9) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.35) 
Using activerecord (3.2.9) 
Using activeresource (3.2.9) 
Using bundler (1.2.3) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.5) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.16.0) 
Using railties (3.2.9) 
Using rails (3.2.9) 
Using acts-as-taggable-on (2.3.3) 
Using backports (2.6.5) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Using blankslate (3.1.2) 
Using sass (3.2.3) 
Using bootstrap-sass (2.2.1.1) 
Using carrierwave (0.7.1) 
Using charlock_holmes (0.6.9) 
Using chosen-rails (0.9.8) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.4.0) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using colored (1.2) 
Using daemons (1.1.9) 
Using orm_adapter (0.4.0) 
Using warden (1.2.1) 
Using devise (2.1.2) 
Using diff-lcs (1.1.3) 
Using draper (0.18.0) 
Using escape_utils (0.2.4) 
Using eventmachine (1.0.0) 
Using multipart-post (1.1.5) 
Using faraday (0.8.4) 
Using ffaker (1.15.0) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
Using font-awesome-sass-rails (2.0.0.0) 
Using foreman (0.60.2) 
Using gemoji (1.2.1) 
Using git (1.2.5) 
Using posix-spawn (0.3.6) 
Using yajl-ruby (1.1.0) 
Using pygments.rb (0.3.2) from https://github.com/gitlabhq/pygments.rb.git (at master) 
Using github-linguist (2.3.4) 
Using github-markup (0.7.4) 
Using gitlab_meta (4.0) 
Using gratr19 (0.4.4.1) 
Using grit (2.5.0) from https://github.com/gitlabhq/grit.git (at 7f35cb9) 
Using hashery (1.5.0) 
Using gitolite (1.1.0) 
Using grack (1.0.0) from https://github.com/gitlabhq/grack.git (at ba46f3b) 
Using hashie (1.2.0) 
Using multi_xml (0.5.1) 
Using rack-accept (0.4.5) 
Using rack-mount (0.8.3) 
Using virtus (0.5.2) 
Using grape (0.2.2) 
Using grit_ext (0.6.1) from https://github.com/gitlabhq/grit_ext.git (at 8e6afc2) 
Using haml (3.1.7) 
Using haml-rails (0.3.5) 
Using httparty (0.9.0) 
Using httpauth (0.2.0) 
Using jquery-atwho-rails (0.1.7) 
Using jquery-rails (2.1.3) 
Using jquery-ui-rails (2.0.2) 
Using jwt (0.1.5) 
Using kaminari (0.14.1) 
Using kgio (2.7.4) 
Using libv8 (3.3.10.4) 
Using modernizr (2.6.2) 
Installing mysql2 (0.3.11) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
root@Server:/home/gitlab/gitlab$
```

Comment: What does the `mkmf.log` file say?

Comment: Have you installed mysql-server?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613116/difficulties-installing-mysql-gem-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 53):

It does tell you a generic possible problem:

> Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
>   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
>   details.  You may need configuration options.

That's your clue.

Make sure you've installed the MySQL client repo, along with the associated "devel" package. Languages like Ruby, Python, Perl, etc., need the libraries and headers installed so they can compile native modules providing the interface from the language to the drivers.

Also, you'll need mysql_config, which is installed by:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

I was able to duplicate your problem with my Ubuntu VM, and fix it after installing libmysqlclient-dev.

It places mysql_config in `/usr/bin/mysql_config`, and both `gem install mysql` and `gem install mysql2` were able to install successfully.

Comment: And what if you have mysql installed in a completely different server, do you still need to install all these packages on the server that runs rvm and rails?

Comment: There are two parts to a MySQL, PostgreSQL or other client/server apps; The client software and the server software. If you are on another machine and want to write code to talk to the server, then, yes, you have to have the client code installed. How would your code talk to the server if it doesn't have access to the client drivers for the server?

Comment: I had the same problem on my MBP, but your answer helped me out. After running `brew install mysql` I was able to run `gem instal mysql2` successfully.

Answer (score 12):

Thank you , It worked, had to just add a few extra stuff

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqld-dev libmysqlclient-dev mysql-client
```

Comment: You said this solution worked for you but you didn't give it the check? Could you accept his answer?

Answer (score 3):

I have used this solution for this problem in rails4: (Ubuntu 12.04)

```
    1) Install MySQL from symptic manager just type "mysql-server-5.5" 
    2) use following command and install 
       sudo apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 8+ x64, please look at the answer provided in the body of this question:

> [Installing MySQL2 Gem on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126326/installing-mysql2-gem-on-windows)

**EDIT**

To make downvoters happy, I'm copying the content of the linked question:

1. Clean up: the reason you're here is that you're probably been trying
   to install this gem, and it has failed, so you have some cleanup to
   do: gem uninstall mysql2
2. Download Ruby 2.0 64 bit for Windows:

> http://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p353-x64.exe?direct

2. Run the installer. Note the directory it installs to, and make sure it's in the User PATH. go to

   ```
   Control Panel > System and Security > System - Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables
   ```

and make sure the path to the bin directory of the ruby install directory is in the PATH environment variable for the LOCAL user (it's also OK if it's in the SYSTEM Path environment variable)

3. Download the Ruby 2 64 bit Dev Kit:

> http://cdn.rubyinstaller.org/archives/devkits/DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe

4. Run the installer and note the location of the install directory. The instructions say that once you're done with the install, you need to run the devkitvars.bat file to set the environment variables. This DOES NOT work for Windows 8.1. You need to repeat the instructions to set the local path described in #2 above, to set the path environment variable for the local user to add the ruby dev kit bin directory, and the ruby dev kit mingw bin directory. For example, if the dev kit was installed to c:\ruby2devkit, and you installed ruby2 to the C:\Ruby200-x64 directory, then your edit your path statement to look like this:

   ```
   C:\Ruby200-x64\bin;C:\ruby2-devkit\bin;c:\ruby2-devkit\mingw\bin
   ```
5. Next you need to install the mysql-connector. DO NOT download and run the self-installer. Instead, download the zip file and unpack it. Note the directory you unpacked it to (for the purposes of this post, let's assume you unpacked it to c:\mysql-connector:

> http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=450612

6. The libmysql.lib included in the MySQL Connector 64 bit is not compatible with the mingw64-gcc compiler. You need to generate mingw64 compatible libmysql.lib file.
7. Download the tools you need

   https://structure-svm-map.googlecode.com/files/svm-map-win.zip
8. Unzip this file to a local directory, let's assume that you unzipped it to c:\svm-map
9. Edit the PATH environment path, as described earlier, to now look like this:

   ```
   C:\Ruby200-x64\bin;C:\ruby2-devkit\bin;c:\ruby2-devkit\mingw\bin;c:\svm-map;C:\svm-map\python-mingw-lib
   ```
10. Generate the new mysql libraries:

    ```
    cd c:\mysql-connector\lib

    gendef.exe libmysql.dll

    dlltool -v --dllname libmysql.dll --def libmysql.def --output-lib libmysql.lib

    copy libmysql.dll C:\Ruby200-x64\bin

    copy libmysql.lib C:\Ruby200-x64\bin
    ```
11. Install the gem as follows (note the use of forward slashes instead of backslashes, it will fail if you use backslashes):

    ```
    gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:/mysql-connector/"'
    ```

Hope this helps, and hopefully someone will pay attention to the few Windows 7/8.1 users who want to do Ruby on Rails development.