# Gem::LoadError Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to run a rails app. Everything is pretty basic.
My gemfile is

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

gem 'mysql2'

database.yml is

development:
  adapter: mysql2

encoding: utf8

database: #new_app_development

pool: 5

username: root

password: password

host: localhost

gem list gives
mysql2 (0.4.0)

but still I'm getting Gem::LoadError
Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile.

I tried both bundle install and gem install mysql2.

Comment: Maybe you need this: [gemload error][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457657/rails-4-gemloaderror-specified-mysql2-for-database-adapter-but-the-gem-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't load mysql2 gem because new version of mysql2(0.4.1) gem unable to load the mysql2_adaptor. This is working for me.

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.13'
```

and run

```
bundle install
```

If still facing problem then [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14177517/3728916) will surely help

**Note:** I'm assuming that you've mysql database installed on your system :P

Answer (score 1):

```
 gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'
```

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)

```
Unknown command mysql2,
```

but

```
gem install mysql2
```

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

> Successfully installed mysql2-0.4.1
>
> 1 gem installed

and then bundle install, but this combination not working

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by `mysql2` just upgraded to `0.4.0` on Sep 8th([see here](https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2)) and it has something compatibility issue with current `rails` version. Because by default, `rails` doesn't specify the version for `mysql2` in the `Gemfile`, so once you issue command `bundle`, `rails` will always install the latest `mysql2` from remote, which is `0.4.0` in this case.

Forturnly, `rails` official has addressed this issue and they will support `mysql2 0.4.0` from next `rails 4.2`([see here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21544))

And obviously, the solution is to downgrade the `mysql2` by spesifying its version to `0.3.x` in the `Gemfile`, like this:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'
```

And then, issue command `bundle`.