# Unable to install mysql2 gem in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I have installed Ruby and Rails. When I run a statement:
`rails new RailsApp -d mysql`
An error has occurred. [This is the image. You can click on it to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJbWg.png)

I tried install it by many ways, but they are not work.

How can I solve it? Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Please do not post images, use plain text instead

Answer (score 0):

looks like you dont have necessary libraries to build the gem. this thread might be usefull to you
[Difficulties installing mysql gem on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613116/difficulties-installing-mysql-gem-on-ubuntu)